# Ember.js RESTAdapter: Access JSON params when setting headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ember.js, ember-data

I am using an API which requires an HMAC sha256 hash of the params inside of the `Authorization` header.

For example, these might be the params:

```
{ "book": { "title": "Test title", "author": "Test author" } }
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to access these params when setting the header.

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://myapi',
    namespace: 'v1',
    shouldReloadAll() { return true; },
    shouldBackgroundReloadRecord() { return true; },
    headers: function() {
        var params = 'PLACE THE PARAMS HERE';
        var hmacString = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256('string', params).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
        return {
            Authorization: hmacString
        }
    }.property("Authorization")
});
```

The above code is working, but I need to replace the `params` variable with the actual params, in JSON format (as above).

How can this be achieved?

Comment: How can we know how to do that if you didn't write how to get actual params?

Comment: @DanielKmak That's exactly the question I am asking. I don't know how to get the params. I know that you can get the params with `ajaxOptions: function(url, type, hash) { this._super(url, type, hash).data }`, but this does not work in the `headers` function. Any ideas?

Comment: No, I was asking about, from where do you get this: `{ "book": { "title": "Test title", "author": "Test author" } }`, for example, do you get them via ajax?

Comment: Those params are an example of what would be sent by DS.RESTAdapter to the API server, as defined in a model elsewhere. They also appear if you call `this._super(url, type, hash).data` in `ajaxOptions`.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to build a dynamical header based on the query params.

I do not think you can get any query params from the `headers` properties, you probably want to try to construct the `header` by overriding the `find*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native way to do that in Ember Data. Your params hash is a data which should be precessed by serializer. But adapter shouldn't care about data, so seems like there's no way to get params in adapter. But you can try to set `headers` from serializer where you have all the data.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    serializeIntoHash: function(data, type, record, options) {
        this._super(data, type, record, options);
        var adapter = this.store.adapterFor(type.modelName);
        var hmacString = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256('string', data).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
        adapter.set('headers', {
            Authorization: hmacString
        });
    }
});
```

I'm not sure this will work, I didn't test it. This is just an idea.